# How do I programmatically simulate resolving a merge conflict with GitPython?

Tags: python, git, git-merge, gitpython

As per my recent question on [merging branches using GitPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799362), I'm trying to unit test the solution there. To do so I need to simulate a user opening their merge tool, resolving the conflicts and committing the result.

If I do this manually using the CLI it all seems to work:

```sh
echo 'Something to resolve the conflict' > conflicted_file.txt
git add conflicted_file.txt
git commit -m "Conflict resolved"
```

I've tried to simulate that same process using GitPython:

```
filename = 'conflicted_file.txt'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write('Some combined content which resolves the merge issue')
# repo is a git.Repo instance
repo.index.add([filename])
repo.index.commit("Simulating user resolving a conflict"+filename)
```

..but this just raises an exception for me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects\grit\test_Gritter.py", line 240, in test_MergeConflicts
    repo.index.commit("Simulating user resolving a conflict"+filename)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\git\index\base.py", line 934, in commit
    tree = self.write_tree()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\git\index\base.py", line 531, in write_tree
    binsha, tree_items = write_tree_from_cache(entries, mdb, slice(0, len(entries)))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\git\index\fun.py", line 234, in write_tree_from_cache
    raise UnmergedEntriesError(entry)
git.exc.UnmergedEntriesError: 100644 fd05580faebf11aee13944da595112eced471664 2 conflicted_file.txt
```

Is there something else I need to mark it as resolved?

**Edit - some more background on what I'm trying to automate**

So just to be clear I want to make it as easy as possible to merge changes in a remote master branch which has been updated into a remote feature branch, resolving any merge conflicts.

As far as I'm aware, the correct way to do that is to:

1. Create a local feature branch
2. Make some changes
3. Push my changes to the remote
4. ...meanwhile someone else merges their changes into the remote master so I now need to merge those changes into my feature branch...
5. Switch to master (on my local checkout)
6. Pull from the remote master to update my local copy
7. Switch to my local feature branch
8. Attempt to merge
9. Resolve any conflicts
10. Push the merge to the remote feature branch

I've got most of this in a single Python script now but the problem this question pertains to is in simulating step 9 in the steps above.

Comment: It too over complicated, Git has more the 6 different way to merge and resolve conflicts.... Are you sure you want to do it :-)

Comment: To clarify, I don't want to handle the conflict resolution in my script, the user's got to do that, but the process of pulling changes from a remote master, merging those into my feature branch, pausing to resolve conflicts then pushing the result into the remote branch ...is something I keep doing again and again  so I've been developing this script to reduce all the typing :)

Comment: Whats wrong with : `git pull ... --rebase`? It will automatically download and merge your code. It will stop if you have conflicts

Comment: Im missing what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is a branch which has already potentially been pushed to a remote repo so I was under the impression I needed to merge rather than rebase. Take a look at the original question for some more background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799362

Comment: You don't have to use rebase, pull will be enough, rebase keep your commits on top

Comment: Added some background. Maybe I'm missing something and there's just a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Since the feature branch has already been pushed, don't rebase.  That will end up with duplicate commits and more confusion further down the line.

Comment: Is there a reason you're pushing an incomplete feature branch?  It would be a lot easier not to do that at all.

Comment: It's not incomplete but we push to gitlab for code review and sometimes when we have a lot going on we have a lot of merges happen in a relatively short space of time. At that point, we have to merge changes which passed code review and made it into the mainline..

Comment: Does it work if you do it as described [in one of the GitPython tests](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/9149c34a8b99052b4e92289c035a3c2d04fb8246/git/test/test_index.py#L550) ? The trick is to set the stage of the index-entry to 0, which is what happens if `git add ...` on the commandline is used. The latter is porcelain, whereas GitPython considers itself plumbing. A lot of control, but at the cost of convenience and intuitiveness.

Comment: I don't know - I tried to disentangle the relevant commands from that huge set of tests but failed miserably. I'd be really interested in seeing how you would do so though if you'd post that as an answer?

Comment: just a small note for future generations: lord @byron was right ;)

indeed, doing `repo.index.reset()` (following by `repo.index.add([ <all your changes>]` of course), helps to fix `git.exc.UnmergedEntriesError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up trying to use the internals of GitPython on the grounds that trying to disentangle the relevent commands from the unit tests was proving rather tricky.

In the end, this worked:

```
g = git.Git('my/repo')
g.execute(["git","add","conflicted_file.txt"])
g.execute(["git","commit","-m", "Conflict resolved"])
```

Answer (score 0):

a small excerpt to show how to simulate programmatically conflicts resolution with GitPython

here, `workdir` is some temporary directory, `repository_url` is your repository URL, `source_branch` is what we need to merge, `target_branch` is where we need to merge, and `process_conflicts` is a function to resolve conflicts (e.g. update conflicted files with proper content).

Note, that this example explicitly creates merge commit (as if with `--no-ff`), but of course it can be changed to ones needs if required, just remove `no_ff=True` and `repo.heads[target_branch],`  in the call to `.merge()`.

```
import os
import shutil

import git
from git.exc import GitCommandError
from git.remote import PushInfo, PushInfoList

# cleanup workdir
shutil.rmtree(workdir, ignore_errors=True)
os.makedirs(workdir, exist_ok=True)

# clone
repo: git.Repo = git.Repo.clone_from(
    url=repository_url, to_path=workdir, branch=target_branch, filter="blob:none"
)

# warm up working trees
repo.git.checkout(source_branch)
repo.git.checkout(target_branch)
message = "My fancy merge commit message"

# merge
try:
    repo.git.merge(
        [repo.heads[target_branch], repo.heads[source_branch]], no_ff=True, m=message
    )
except GitCommandError as ex:
    if not "CONFLICT" in ex.stdout:
        raise ex
    conflicted_files = [
        os.path.join(workdir, line.split(" ")[-1])
        for line in ex.stdout.split("\n")
        if line.startswith("CONFLICT")
    ]
    # here we process conflict, e.g. write new contents of our files
    process_conflicts(conflicted_files)

    # now for the magic part
    repo.index.reset()
    repo.index.add([workdir])
    repo.index.commit(
        message=message, 
        parent_commits=[repo.heads[target_branch].commit, repo.heads[source_branch].commit]  # type: ignore
    ) 

# all set, push it
push_result: PushInfoList = repo.remote("origin").push(target_branch)
push_result.raise_if_error()
```